# python comprehension loop for dictionary

Tags: python

Beginner question.

I have a dictionary as such:

```
tadas = {'tadas':{'one':True,'two':2}, 'john':{'one':True,'two':True}}
```

I would like to count the True values where key is 'one'. How should I modify my code?

```
sum(x == True for y in tadas.values() for x in y.values() )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access only the one attribute:

```
sum(item['one'] for item in tadas.values())
```

This makes use of the fact, that `True` is equal to `1` and `False` is equal to `0`.

If not every item contains the key `'one'` you should use the `.get` method:

```
sum(item.get('one', 0) for item in tadas.values())
```

`.get` returns the second argument, if the dict does not contain the first argument.

If `'one'` can also point to numbers, you should explictly test for `is True`:

```
sum(item.get('one', 0) is True for item in tadas.values())
```

If you dont want to hide the summation in the boolean, you can do it more explicitly with:

```
sum(1 if item.get('one', False) is True else 0 for item in tadas.values())
```

Comment: While it's technically true that `1 + True == 2`, it feels like a code smell to me, something that made it all the way from C to Python 3 ;-)

Comment: I added a more explicit version

Comment: But `True == 1` so that wouldn't catch the case where the value is the particular number 1. This is why I'm suspicious of smelly code.

Comment: But `True is not 1`, so better use that.

Comment: See... better now ;-)

Answer (score 3):

List can count occurrences of values, so making use of that is probably most idiomatic:

```
[x.get('one') for x in tadas.values()].count(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
print(sum(1 for x in tadas.values() if x['one']))
```

NOTE: please do not use this answer as it's definitely not as good as other answers.

Comment: Or, since booleans are just wrapped integers in Python, you could just do `sum(x['one'] for x in tadas.values())`

Comment: To avoid a KeyError, perhaps you could use x.get('one').

Comment: @ap, that's why i love SO - everyday i'm learning something new, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter to filter the list of any values where 'one' doesn't map to True.  Then, just return the length of the list.

```
len(filter(lambda x: tadas[x]['one'], tadas))
```

Comment: This answer only applies if the question indeed refers to any values that evaluate to True. Maybe the asker should clarify this point.